# Application crashes whenever instantiating (empty) constructor

Tags: java, android, ant, extension-methods, runtimeexception

I'm creating an **Android** extension intended to connect to a remote SSH host based on the well known [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library, so that once the button is pressed, the class is instantiated this way, with **no** compilation error:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
```

...but, application crashes!

Looking at the **JSch()** constructor, there is nothing inside:

```
public JSch(){
// here there are several commented instructions that need to be
// used just at MAC operational systems (not my OS).
}
```

If I remove initiation, compiler complains that variable **jsch** is not initalized.

```
JSch jsch;
```

Once I'm compiling with **Apache Ant**, there is no debug resources that I could use to trace the runtime error.

All tests are being made either within threads or callback methods, giving the same result; I simply cannot initiate the jsch variable, this yields a runtime exception **com.jcraft.jsch.JSch**.
Does someone has some insights on how to solve that issue ?

Comment: Can you pls share the error stacktrace?

Comment: Is there any static initialization code in JSch?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the Java stack trace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: There is no way to do that, the application run at a mobile that is not connected to anything, I mean, the .apk package is being downloaded via MIT APP INVENTOR companion tool via Wi-fi connection so that as said, there is no debug resources available so far.

Comment: @CommonsWare 1, thanks for your reply, but I'm using an outdated toolset, the Apache Ant, which just build and I have no access to the Mobile in debug mode.

Comment: Um, you are going to need to address that. If you have no access to debug logs, I have no idea how you will succeed. Taking some blind guesses: make sure you are requesting the `INTERNET` permission, and make sure that you only use `Jsch` on a background thread.

Comment: Regardless of anything, by focusing on the code above, are my observations correct? I mean, if the constructor is empty, should the simple instantiation at runtime cause runtime error?

Comment: Yes, I've added: @UsesPermissions(permissionNames = "android.permission.INTERNET")   **Note** *This is an Android extension*

Comment: In short, the question is more related to language itself; based on what was presented in the above question, am I having wrong assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the *Android* **SDK-tools** and after capturing the Log via line command **ADB logcat > file.txt**, there were the following sentence many times:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jcraft.jsch.JSch

Which means that the extension file (.aix) compiled with apache command **ant extensions** did not embed the above class within it.
This explains the issue at all (application crashing instantiating above constructor - absent), and the next step is to discover how to encapsulate dependencies - surely in another thread, if I will not be able to do on my own.

Comment: Anyway it is weird, once 'ant' did not issued compilation error anytime.